# Outerjoin in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a `posts` collection in the following format:

```
{
    reqID: Int32
    chatID: Int64
    messageID: Int32
    visits: Int32
}
```

I also have a `user` collection which has an array field named `visits`:

```
visits: [
{
    chatID: Int64
    messageID: Int32
    lastVisit: Int64
}
]
```

I want to select every `post` from the first collection where the desired `user` has not visited it in last 24 hrs. Well this is an outer join, but MongoDB has limited support for outer joins only using `$lookup` which is appropriate only for simple foreign key lookup. Are there any tricks which can help me to find what I want internally in DMBS?

Comment: No, MongoDB does not do JOINs, also MR will not do this, even $lookup is not actually a JOIN but is a physical look up

Comment: Does the `visits` field in the `posts` collection hold a reference to the `user` collection?

Comment: @chridam No but I can use references if needed. Do you have any ideas? Please write as an answer.

Comment: I've got an idea but would need some clarification before posting the answer as it can be in vain if otherwise. What is the relationship between the `posts` and `users` collections? Is `chatID` or `messageID` the link between the two?

Comment: Thanks in prior. `chatID` and `messageID` both are unique but can't be used as a reference to `users`. So I may use `_Id` of each user as reference in my schema if needed, Each `user` visits some posts which is specified via `chatID` and `messageID` (and earns credits by doing so)  and each user can make an order (which will be stored in `posts` collection) so that other users visit their post. In `users` document I record every visit (made to any post) which is done by that user, in `visits` field.